# XML parser error handling

Tags: xml, parsing

I would very much appreciate your help with this. 
Basically, I have a PHP webpage, where the user chooses a city name (by its code) and this is then sent to a script, which finds the city in a database, gets an XML file associated with it, which contains its current weather, and then displays it.
It all works fine except when the user selects a code, which does not exist. What then happens is that I get the message:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in ...
```

The major problem with that is, that it stops all loading, so not only does the user see this, but also, the rest of the page including HTML and everything is just not loaded.

What I would like is to have some sort of a check, that in case the file is not found has a wrong structure, simply echoes some message like "Error, city not found" and skips the rest of the script, but loads the rest of the webpage, its HTML etc.

I found some solutions on the internet but I was not able to implement it successfully.

The code that loads the actual xml looks like this:

```
public function __construct($query, $units = 'imperial', $lang = 'en', $appid = ''){

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(OpenWeatherMap::getRawData($query, $units, $lang, $appid, 'xml'));

$this->city = new _City($xml->city['id'], 
$xml->city['name'], 
$xml->city->coord['lon'], 
$xml->city->coord['lat'], 
$xml->city->country);

etc.
```

In case the city is not found, instead of XML, the program gets this:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=123456

In case it is found, it gets this:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&mode=xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

btw to avoid throwing errors at users, it's good to set some of  these php options so errors are logged to apache server log or a separate file, but not shown to the user. THis is good also from security point of view:
http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php

update: I see [a nice guide](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/30/a-guide-to-php-error-messages-for-designers/) for setting the error logging options.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of SimpleXMLElement, the constructor will throw an exception if the file could not be parsed.  I would try wrapping it in a try-catch:

```
try {
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(...);
  // The xml loaded, so display the proper information.
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // If it gets here, the xml could not load, so print your 'city not found' message and continue loading the page.
}
```

What happens is, it will attempt to construct a new SimpleXMLElement object, but the constructor will 'throw' an error.  Normally a throw will stop everything in its tracks, but since you are 'catching' it, you are explicitly saying, "hey, if there is a problem, return control back to me and let me decide what to do about it".